# how to access an array within a json php to javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, websocket

I have this function in  php

```
$everything= array($ary);
$response = (json_encode(array('code'=>'0','id'=>$id,'usr'=>$usr, 'everything'=>$everything)));
```

how can i access this using javascript/jquery.I have this at the moment.

**javascript**

```
 websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
   received = JSON.parse(ev.data);
   var everything = received.everything;
 };
```

I am able to get all data except for the varible `$everything` how can I pass it from `php` and retrive it over in `javascript`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: okay i can give u the full code but not here personally or something and i would appreciate it if you won't share it with any one else ?

Comment: No. The code that produces the problem needs to be inside the question, otherwise the question is useless. Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this is the code that is the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a better way to do this is to use the implode function in php 
to convert the arrays in to strings and then pass it

```
$everything= array($ary);
 ConvertEverything = implode(' ',$everything);
$response = (json_encode(array('code'=>'0','id'=>$id,'usr'=>$usr, 'everything'=>$ConvertEverything )));
```

**JavaScript**

```
 websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
   received = JSON.parse(ev.data);
   var everything = received.everything;
 };
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
$response = json_encode(array('code'=>'0','id'=>$id,'usr'=>$usr, 'everything'=>$ary));
```

It will work perfectly for you.

Comment: and how would i call this from javascript/jquery ? please provide full answers

Comment: as. you told everything is working perfectly rather then everything value.  I don know that much about websocket.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the index ex. received[0]

```
websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
  received = JSON.parse(ev.data); 
  var everything = received[0].everything; 
  document.write(everything);            
};
```

Comment: Never use `document.write`

Comment: just for checking response

Comment: Then use `console.log()`

Comment: doesnt work for some reason says uncaught can not read property everything but i have defined it in php

Comment: `received` is an object not an array.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$everything= array($ary);
$response = (json_encode(array('code'=>'0','id'=>$id,'usr'=>$usr, 'everything'=>$everything)));
?>
<script>
websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
var code = ev.data;
var id= ev.id;
var usr = ev.usr;

        };

</script>
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code in to an answer. Remember, we're here to educate people, so please take the time to explain what the issue is an how your answer helps solve it.

Comment: That aside, your logic is broken as the response has no `data` property.

Comment: already tried that it can get data for single variables but how to get it for `everything` as` everything` is an array

Comment: print($response);

Comment: This makes no sense. You can't send headers in a WebSocket message.